# Setting default browser with powershell without 'How do you want to open this?' prompts

Tags: powershell, default-browser

all,

I recently tried to setup edge as a default bowser in a login script.

```
#Edge
Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice' -name ProgId IE.HTTP
Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice' -name ProgId IE.HTTPS

#Chrome
# Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice' -name ProgId ChromeHTML
# Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice' -name ProgId ChromeHTML
```

However, when I attempt to open a link in an email, I get a prompt on 'how I would like to open this? ' no matter which browser I set as default?

[image: How do you want to open this?]

Is is possible to set a registry key to turn off these prompts in windows?

Ta,

X

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm unsure if the following will solve your problem, but it's better to use a `ProgId` value  of `MSEdgeHTM` for Microsoft Edge (for *both* `http://` and `https://`):

```bash
'http', 'https' | ForEach-Object {
  $regPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\$_\UserChoice"
  Set-ItemProperty $regPath ProgId MSEdgeHTM
}
```

Note:

- At least in URL shortcuts and `Start-Process` calls with URLs the above is effective for me on my Windows 11 22H2 system, without prompting.
- However, you *will* get a `Select an app to open this .<ext> file` dialog on opening HTML *files*.